# Use a secondary WiFi router as a file server?

Tags: wireless-router

I bought myself a brand new router - which i quite enjoy.. big surprise it has dual wan capability, wasn't expecting that for a $20 router.

I'm quite pleased, however - it does have one feature I would like to use that my old router has but this doesn't.

My TP Link router has the ability to attach an HD via USB and share it on the network.

So, what I'm wondering is... can I somehow set up this TP Link in another room and just use it as a file server somehow... attach a USB to it. Either by plugging in an ethernet cable or somehow configuring something so that it talks to the ASUS wirelessly?

- *but still keeping the ASUS as the incoming WAN Internet Router*
- goal is to have the TP LINK somehow on the same LAN network as the ASUS sharing the USB HD as its sole purpose
- [TP LINK TL-WR1043ND - note: I have V1](http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WR1043ND_V1.html)
- [ASUS RT-N12 D1](https://www.asus.com/Networking/RTN12_D1/)

Comment: I would not suggest this unless [the manufacturer has patched this vulnerability](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2924472/critical-vulnerability-in-netusb-driver-exposes-millions-of-routers-to-hacking.html)

Comment: this affects ASUS as well or just TP LINK? maybe I can run some 3rd party firmware on the TP LINK? The ASUS firmware is pretty new but the TP LINK is about 2 years old

Comment: actually the HD I want to attach is only for media files, not any kind of sensitive info - movies and music

Comment: Does the TPlink have AP mode? It might be a simple matter of doing that (or turning off the DHCP server) and just... doing it

Comment: Did you even read the article? "As far as the Sec Consult researchers know, only TP-Link has released fixes so far. It has a release schedule for around 40 products." So check for a firmware update from TP link and your model.

Comment: You can put the tplink in bridge mode by doing what Journeyman Geek suggested and accomplish what you want, Why not just share that drive from a pc of choice on your network?

Comment: I don't really have any PCs constantly on - or even connected by ethernet (I think that is required for Wake On Lan, right? you can't WoL over wifi?)